# How to delete values from two tables?

Tags: c#, gridview, outer-join

I have a medicalcentre table and windowadmin table which have relationship with each other using mcID. I display mcType and mcCentre first which exist in medicalcentre table to a gridview, after that I use outer join to display winusername field and winPassword field in windowsadmin table to a gridview. What I want to achieve is to use the delete function to delete a record. But I got error, see the 3rd image.

**My windowsadmin and medicalcentre table**
[image]

**My windowsadmin and medicalcentre table relationship**
[image]

**My form**
[image]

**My Error**
[image]

```
private void LoadMedicalCentreRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT cen.mcid, mcType, mcCentre, win.winUsername, win.winPassword FROM MEDICALCENTRE AS cen";
            strCommandText += " LEFT OUTER JOIN WINDOWSADMIN as win on cen.mcid = win.mcid";
            MedicalCentreAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            //SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(MedicalCentreAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            MedicalCentre.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            MedicalCentreAdapter.Fill(MedicalCentre);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (MedicalCentre.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdMc.DataSource = MedicalCentre;
        }




private int DeleteMedicalCentreRecord()
        {
            // no row in GridView selected
            if (currentRow == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "DELETE FROM WINDOWSADMIN WHERE winID=@WINID; DELETE FROM MEDICALCENTRE WHERE mcID=@MCID;";
            SqlCommand deleteCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

            // Cell - contains employee ID
            int winID = Convert.ToInt32(currentRow.Cells[0].Value);
            int mcID = Convert.ToInt32(currentRow.Cells[0].Value);
            deleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WINID", winID);
            deleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCID", mcID);           
            //// STEP 3: open connection and retrieve data by calling ExecuteReader
            myConnect.Open();
            //STEP 4: execute command
            int result = deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // STEP 5: Close
            myConnect.Close();
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a foreign key there with ON DELETE RESTRICT?

Comment: I dun think so, how do i check it? erm Before i use outer join, i was able to delete just the fields from medicalcentre table, but after outer joining with windowsadmin table and writing the delete code also for windowsadmin fields. The error came out @Vlad Schnakovszki

Comment: Could you show the SQL code that creates the FK_WINDOWSADMIN_MEDICALCENTER foreign key?

Comment: Code? I created the relationship by clicking. SEe the 2nd image @Steve

Comment: OK that's the same. But are you sure that when you delete an mcID there are no more user in the WindowsAdmin table with that mcID that are not deleted by the previous query?

Comment: I mean: a record with `winID=1,mcID=1` another record with `winID=2,mcID=1`. in this scenario you cannot delete mcID=1 alone, but you have to remove every user in the WindowsAdmin table whose mcID is 1

Comment: I change my first image to the latest. I try to delete the 5th record which is test, and the error came out. And to answer your question, as u can see in my latest 1st image, all my mcid is unique. 1,3,4,7,9. Ok i just saw your latest answer, will go try it. @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your DELETE commands to

```
string strCommandText = @"DELETE FROM WINDOWSADMIN WHERE mcID=@MCID; 
                          DELETE FROM MEDICALCENTRE WHERE mcID=@MCID;";
```

This ensure that every win user that has a releationship with the medical center that you want to delete will be deleted from the WindowsAdmin table

In other words, you can delete every record you like in the WINDOWSADMIN table but you cannot delete a record in the MEDICALCENTRE table if there is a record in the WINDOWSADMIN table that still REFERENCES the record in medicalcentre that you want to delete